# Проектирование интерфейса веб-проектов

Tags: проектирование, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток. Прошу помочь с поиском программных средств для проектирования интерфейса веб-страниц. Интересует не первая ссылка из результатов запроса в Google, а именно те инструменты, которыми Вы пользовались и остались довольны.

- Страницы верстаются для вывода на ПК и планшеты, другие устройства не интересуют.
- Желательно чтобы искомый программный продукт был бесплатным или хотя бы имел тестовый период.
- Поддержка русского языка в проектировщике не обязательна.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Забыл отписать, что ПО ищу под Linux.
Или хотя бы с возможностью запуска под Wine

Comment: Не frone-end разработка, а именно проектирование интерфейса. Как в Visio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если просто эскизы набрасывать, кроссплатформенно и бесплатно - попробуйте [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/). Он построен на базе Firefox'a - запустится везде.

Кроме того, есть немало онлайн-сервисов разной степени бесплатности, решающих данную задачу. Из того, чем я пользовался:

- [Cacoo](https://cacoo.com/)
- [Mockingbird](https://gomockingbird.com/)
- [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/uses/wireframe-software/)

У всех есть свои удобства/неудобства. Лучше каждый пощупать самому и выбрать. Последние два для меня были интересны интеграцией с продуктами Atlassian.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если вы ищите программу-конструктор для автоматического рендеринга и создания верстки страницы, т.е. самого  `HTML + CSS`, то вам подойдет `Macromedia Dreamweaver` или `Microsoft Word`, но скажу честно, ни одна программа за вас хорошо не сверстает, даже если вы ее напишете сами, так что учите верстку, а если вам надо просто нарисовать интерфейс, то я соглашусь с ответом пользователя [@Nofate](/users/1984/nofate), и с его предложением по поводу `Pencil`. Дерзайте!

Comment: Нет, Вы немного неправильно поняли мой вопрос. Adobe Dreamweaver немного не подходит, а вот Microsoft Word — уж точно не то =)
Мне нужно создавать именно прототип интерфейса, его предварительный проект, грубо выражаясь.
В любом случае, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: > вам подойдет Macromedia Dreamweaver или Microsoft Word

Вы видели, ''какой'' код они дают на выходе?

Дримвивер еще терпимо, но Ворд...